# Why can't write info into /tmp directory instead of /var/www/html?

Tags: php, file-put-contents

LAMP installed on my local pc, as I know the string `xxxx` can be written into `/tmp/test` with below PHP function.

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/test","test1 test2")
```

`cat ajax_get.php`

```
<?php
    $str = "test1 test2";
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $str = implode(" ",$_GET);
    file_put_contents("/tmp/test",$str);
    print($str);
?>
```

Why the command `file_put_contents("/tmp/test",$str);` in `ajax_get.php` can't work?

It is no use to replace `file_put_contents` with

```
$handle=fopen("/tmp/test","w");
fwrite($handle,$str);
fclose($handle);
```

Maybe it is an issue on directory permission, if I change below statement in `ajax_get.php`

```
    file_put_contents("/tmp/test",$str);
```

Into

```
    file_put_contents("test",$str);
```

And run the previous process, `ajax_get.php` create a file in `/var/www/html/test`

```
cat /var/www/html/test
test1 test2
```

Show the permission for `/tmp` directory.

```
ls -al /tmp
total 76
drwxrwxrwt 16 root    root    12288 Dec 10 18:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root     4096 Dec  1 08:03 ..
```

`.` is the current directory `/tmp`, its permission is 777 (rwxrwxrwx),
why can't write file into `/tmp` directory by PHP?

Comment: check required permissions to create new file on path, if permissions available then set required permissions of file to write contents in it.

Comment: In linux,any user can write file into the directory `/tmp`.

Comment: Are there any error messages? Whave have you tried to debug this?

Comment: No any other error messages.

Comment: put file writting code in TRY CATCH block to check if any exception occures.

Comment: @ManojSingh none of the used functions throw exceptions in the first place, so trying to catch any does make little sense at this point.

Comment: @misorude file handling code should be in a try catch block

Comment: @ManojSingh none of the functions used here _can_ throw an exception, so using try/catch makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: @misorude it was just a suggestion to find out any possible exception... as i am in habbit to use try catch for code used for file handling or db operations.

Comment: Show more info in my revised post,it is a issue on directory permission.

Comment: Have you verified the return of `file_put_contents("/tmp/test",$str);`? E.g. `$ret = file_put_contents("/tmp/test",$str);`. This would tell you if you are actually writing any bytes or not.

Comment: You really need to define what “can’t” means here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are not sharing with us the return of `file_put_contents("/tmp/test",$str);`, but I'm going to assume that you are actually writing the appropriate bytes.

Being that the case, and considering the permissions look OK and that you don't say that are getting an error message, the most likely scenario is a problem with `systemd` configuration.

Your Apache/PHP process are writing to that location correctly, but [systemd has a configuration setting that allows for each process to have its own `/tmp` directory](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1976243).

> ```
> PrivateTmp=
>     Takes a boolean argument. If true sets up a new file system
>      namespace for the executed processes and mounts a 
>      private /tmp directory inside it, that is not shared by     
>      processes outside of the namespace. This is useful to secure 
>      access to temporary files of the process, but makes sharing
>      between processes via /tmp impossible. 
>
> Defaults to false.
> ```

In this case, the `tmp` you see as a regular or root user is not the same `tmp` directory that apache/php sees. Read more about this [here](https://www.philipp-wagner.com/blog/2014/04/does-tmp-have-a-split-personality), for example.

You could disable the `PrivateTmp` setting for Apache, but I think it would be easier to choose a different path to store your files, and give the apache/PHP process permission to write there.

There could be other possible explanations for not being able to write to `tmp` despite the directory permissions: e.g. that that directory was not added to the [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) directive, or that somehow [the directory immutable attribute got set](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#File_attributes) (very unlikely for `/tmp`). But in any of these cases, you would be getting an error message.

Comment: I don't think the OP means that the file isn't showing up in the /tmp folder which is what PrivateTmp=true would cause. I think he means that the file is not writing at all or else why mention the permissions on the /tmp folder being drwxrwxrwt and thus writable. But it's hard to tell what he means because we do not know the return value of file_put_contents(). In my case PHP can't write to /tmp and file_put_contents() returns false even though the permissions are set to drwxrwxrwt on /tmp so your answer doesn't help me. This behavior began after Apache automatically updated to Apache/2.4.29

Comment: @PHPGuru Considering the OP accepted the answer and awarded the bounty, it seems I got what they needed with this answer. Not sure why you think you know better "what the OP meant". I'm sad the answer does not solve your issue. At least it helps you by eliminating another cause. With more information someone else might be able to help you. Bye!

Comment: I asked my question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1069069/php-cant-write-to-tmp-folder-anymore-after-apache-update

Answer (score -3):

The return values of the `file_get_contents` method explains on the [php manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) page as ***This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.*** So `file_get_contents`it's must be a return. First, you have to check this returns.

Second, you wants create a file to a folder that looks like has a permission only root user. Apache user has not root permission, so you can't write. Please check this [url](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) for permissions and I suggest to you be careful when you changing permission of folders.

Comment: If you read the question, are using file_PUT_contents, not get one. And folder .. are the parent, not the current one.